# Ordering by a column in an associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I am trying to make an ActiveRecord query that will order the results by the value of one of the columns in an associated model:

I have a Chats model that has a `one to many` relationship with the messages model.

`Chats has_many messages` and `Message belongs_to chat`

And from my controller, I want to get a list of chats, ordered by the `created_at` of the associated message.first, eg:

```
@chats = current_user.chats.includes(:messages).order("messages.first.created_at").paginate(page: params[:page])
```

or something like that.

My question is that how can I achieve this kind of ordering from an associated model with this relationship? All contributions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, @Rubyrider and @Andrew. I have been able to order the columns as follow:

```
@chats = current_user.chats.includes(:messages).order("messages.created_at desc").paginate(page: params[:page])
```

without the inclusion of either `.first` or `.last` on messages. Surprisingly, I did not have to specify which of the messages of the chat is to be used for the ordering. I guess `ActiveRecord` automatically looks and just takes the latest of the associated model to use for the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Also add .references(:messages)

This will pull messages in as a join rather than a separate query.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your order in your association. Try the following:

```
has_many messages, -> { order(:created_at => :asc) }
# change how you need
```

So when you call `chat.messages` it will return messages with the given order.

Comment: thanks, but maybe I was not clear enough. I am not ordering messages, I want to order chats. chat belongs_to user for example, and if I call `user.chats`, I want to order the chats by which one has the latest message, thanks